# Bind a QueryString that has arrays with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using the Telerk Kendo UI grid that loads data remotely. The `QueryString` passed into my action method looks like this:-

```
take=10&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=10&sort[0][field]=value&sort[0][dir]=asc
```

I am trying to work out how to bind the `sort` parameter into my method? Is it possible or do I need to enumerate through the `QueryString` collection manually or create a custom binder?

So far I have tried this:-

```
public JsonResult GetAllContent(int page, int take, int pageSize, string[] sort)

public JsonResult GetAllContent(int page, int take, int pageSize, string sort)
```

but sort is always null. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

I can fall back to Request.QueryString using, but this is a bit of a kludge.

```
var field = Request.QueryString["sort[0][field]"];
var dir = Request.QueryString["sort[0][dir]"];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an array of dictionaries:

```
public ActionResult Index(
    int page, int take, int pageSize, IDictionary<string, string>[] sort
)
{
    sort[0]["field"] will equal "value"
    sort[0]["dir"] will equal "asc"
    ...
}
```

and then define a custom model binder:

```
public class SortViewModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
        var keys = controllerContext
            .HttpContext
            .Request
            .Params
            .Keys
            .OfType<string>()
            .Where(key => key.StartsWith(modelName));

        var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            var val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);
            result[key.Replace(modelName, "").Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "")] = val.AttemptedValue;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

which will be registered in Global.asax:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(IDictionary<string, string>), new SortViewModelBinder());
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, This is one of the reasons I love Stack Overflow.

Comment: Using the IDictionary array to capture the sorting criteria is the cleanest implementation that I have found online so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For asp.net core I didn't use a model binder, as the data is sent as a Dictionary I just used the following method signature on my api and the binding happened automatically (no parameter mapping required client side)

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GetAccessions(.., IDictionary<string, string>[] sort)
{
    ...
}
```