# Model binding the sort field from KendoUI Grid

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding, kendo-ui

I'm using KendoUI Grid to show data. I have server paging working like a charm. The each page change in the kendo grid is a new ajax request to the server and the server returns the correct page of data. I am now trying to do server-side sorting, but I'm having trouble getting model binding to bind to the sort values.

This is what the request from the Kendo Grid looks like:

[image]

My action method looks like this:

```
public JsonResult GetReports(int pageSize, int skip, List<KendoSort> sort)
{
    // sort is not being populated with the right data.
}
```

KendoSort is a custom class:

```
public class KendoSort
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Dir { get; set; }
}
```

I know I'm not doing this right. How should my action method look to correctly capture the data supplied for the sort? The screenshot shows only a single item in the sort collection, but the grid could pass more. For example, it could also have included an additional sort:

```
sort[1][field]: reportName
sort[1][dir]: asc
```

Basically it would be saying "sort by id in ascending order, then by reportName in ascending order". How can I get this data into my action method without having to poke around in `Request` and manually parse the parameters?

Comment: Why don't use use the built in `DataSourceRequest` with the `DataSourceRequestModelBinder` as your action parameter? Then your action would look like  `public JsonResult GetReports([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)` where the request object contains all the needed data.

Comment: I suppose I could go that route. I have yet to add the Kendo Mvc binaries to the project. Was going with a pure HTML5 approach. I suppose I can still do that but use some of the server-side niceties like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ASP.NET MVC model binder does not understand expressions like `sort[0][field]`. It understands only `sort[0].field` which is unfortunate because `jQuery.ajax` submits nested objects in the former format.

There are two ways to solve the problem:

1. Use Kendo UI Complete for ASP.NET MVC. It comes with a built-in model for the grid request. More info can be found [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-binding).
2. Create a [parameterMap](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#transportparametermap-function) and translate the sort expression:

   ```
   parameterMap: function(options) {
        var result = {
          pageSize: options.pageSize,
          skip: options.skip
        };

        if (options.sort) {
            for (var i = 0; i < options.sort.length; i++) {
               result["sort[" + i + "].field"] = options.sort[i].field;
               result["sort[" + i + "].dir"] = options.sort[i].dir;
            }
        }

        return result;
   }
   ```

---

#### UPDATE FROM QUESTION AUTHOR:

I did end up using parameter map, but rather than re-structure the sort field I simply stringified the options and specified the contentType on the CRUD transports. The model binder knows to bind to the stringified JSON as long as the contentType is specified.

```
transport: {
    read: {
        url: '...',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    },
    update: {
        url: '...',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    },
    destroy: {
        url: '...',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    },
    create: {
        url: '...',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    },
    parameterMap: function (options, type) {
        return JSON.stringify(options);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll accept your answer because I used parameterMap but I am going to append your answer with what I actually did.

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer from another thread using `IDictionary<string, string>[] sort`, which seems to be the most elegant and cleanest way to capture the sort criteria on the server side. I don't use a custom model binder as the sample code showed. I simply capture the sorting criteria using IDictionary array and then apply that criteria to my own data source. Here is the link to that discussion thread: [Using IDictionary array to capture Kendo UI sorting criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557818/bind-a-querystring-that-has-arrays-with-mvc)

Comment: Thanks! This is in fact much simpler than the accepted answer.