# MVC 3 Model Binder does not populate object properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, modelbinder

MVC Kendo Grid calls an update method, and using fiddler I can see the objects data in the query string.  In debug mode I can also see that the model binder was able to identify the number of objects in the query string.  But when I look at my object list none of the values came across. I don't where else to look for possible solutions at this point.

Razor view:
[image]

Fiddler:
[image]

HTTP Request:
GET [OMITTED ON PURPOSE]MultipleTaxTypesUpdate?models%5B0%5D%5BTaxId%5D=33a34b0e-06a1-415b-b2c7-c155839123d6&models%5B0%5D%5BName%5D=Event+Taxes&models%5B0%5D%5BExternalCode%5D=3

Debug View:
[image]

In the debug view, notice how 1 object was detected but the properties are empty.  If I update 2 objects, I would have 2 empty objects on the Debug View.

Model View

```
using System;
namespace ECM.DAL.ViewModels.Taxes
{
    public class TaxTypeViewModel
    {
        public Guid TaxId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ExternalCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know Kendo but for the model binder to work you need `models[0].TaxId` not `models[0][TaxId]` as `TaxTypeViewModel` has no string indexer.

Comment: Hmmm... I think you are onto something. Let me chase that lead.

Comment: @BitsandBytesHandyman http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004986/model-binding-the-sort-field-from-kendoui-grid

Comment: Thank you both. It turned out the I have both Telerik and Kendo UI running side by side, and Kendo requires jquery 1.9.1 >= and Telerik <= 1.7.1 So I cant run it side by side.  There is a known problem with Kendo serializing the data appropriately with jquery 1.7.1, which is the problem with the missing dot.  Thank you again.